# Correct diameter and name for wire for LED cathode connection

Tags: wire

I'm building an 8x8x8 LED cube kit like this:
[image]

But I'm not happy with the wire provided for connecting the cathodes to the board as it's red and ugly.

I'm looking to purchase a better substitute for it - something metallic looking (preferably silver to help conceal it) but insulated.  White would work as well.

My problem?  I don't know how to search for it online - I don't know the correct diameter or how to refer to the wire properly to find exactly what I need online.

What diameter is proper, and how should I refer to it when searching?

EDIT TO ADD:  In the packing list from the kit (amazon.com) this was the contents description:

- Includes: Blue LED's (512 pcs) PCB board USB power cable 40P round female power pin DIP-40 IC socket x2 STC12C5A60S2 (code pre-loaded) DIP-20 IC socket x9 SN74HC573AN x9 DIP-18 socket ULN2803APG A103J Resistor 10uf electrolytic capacitor x2 crystal oscillator 22pf ceramic capacitor x2 470 ohm resistor x8 4.7k ohm resistor x2 DC005 socket Self-locking push switch **Red LED 0.8 Single Conductor**

I'm thinking that the bold "Red LED 0.8 Single Conductor" is the description of the wire included - so would that be 0.8mm?

Comment: Does the cube spec out its estimated (or max) current or power consumption?

Comment: There are no specs or instructions.  This was a kit bought online and I've been figuring out the build by studying youtube videos and instructables links.

Comment: Do you have a way to measure the supplied wire? Does it have any markings on it?

Comment: If it did, I've rendered it unreadable.  The wire was originally red and I thought to try to make it less visible by coloring it black with permanent marker.  It's less visible than the red, but I'm still not happy.

Comment: If it's at all helpful, the cube is powered by USB connection, 5v.

Comment: More info added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 0.8 is the diameter (in mm) for the red single-conductor, that corresponds to 20AWG wire, which seems appropriate for the use in question.  So what you want to search for is 20AWG Single-Conductor Wire in your color of choice (unlikely to come in a metallic silver, but possibly in gray and most definitely in white).  From electronics distributors like DigiKey and Newark, it's labeled as "hook-up wire".

Comment: I would consider  30 gauge magnet wire.. even smaller and burn thru the connection insulation with 3seconds of tiny solder dot for rows or column current and AWG 20 magnet wire for main current. All neatly routed and tacked with instant adhesive when working.This is often used in production for ECN jumpers.

Comment: Based on pictures of assembled kits, it looks like the LEDs themselves are assembled in a cube just using the leads, while the 20AWG carries the current for each LED plane to ground (in what appears to be parallel connections).

Comment: @ChrisM. that is correct - 8x8 grid of annodes and 8 cathode planes.  The jumper is used to connect each plane to the board.  Because of that I think I'll stick with the wider 20AWG gauge.